# Access add new line to table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have sub that runs when the database is opened to a specific form and I'm trying to get it to add information in a table.

The table name is UnAuthorizedAccess and the columns in table are ID(auto number), NAME(text),  COMPUTERNAME(text), ATTEMPTDATE(date/time).

What commands do I need to use to add a new record to this table? I have a VBA that if they're login information Isn't there is will force close access all together. I'm trying to gather information on the user as well before kicking them out.

I figured this is the easiest way as outlook won't let you send a hidden email from the user unless they first see it.

Comment: "I figured this is the easiest way as outlook won't let you send a hidden email from the user unless they first see it". As far as I am aware, this statement isn't entirely true. I am pretty sure I run hidden emails all the time on my database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add records to a recordset with the following code, but I am unsure whether you have a field called `COMPUTERNAME`. You shouldn't need to add the `ID` value as its an autonumber.

```
dim Rst as recordset      
Set Rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Name:="UnauthorizedAccess", Type:=RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset)
         With Rst
            .AddNew
            ![NAME] = Me.Name.Value
            ![COMPUTERNAME] = Me.COMPUTERNAME.Value
            ![ATEMPTDATE] = date()
            .Update
         End With
```

As for sending hidden emails, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36328068/5043393) question I asked not so long ago. It sends an email via outlook, but remember to reference the `Microsoft Outlook Object library` in the VBA Editor.

Answer (score 0):

`CurrentDB.Execute` is the method for executing SQL statements, and `INSERT INTO` is the SQL statement for adding records to a DB table.

```
CurrentDB.Execute "INSERT INTO UnAuthorizedAccess (NAME, COMPUTERNAME, ATTEMPTDATE) " & _
"VALUES (" & Your_NAME_Variable & ", " & Your_COMPUTERNAME_Variable  & ", " & Now() & ")
```

Replace `Your_NAME_Variable` and `Your_COMPUTERNAME_Variable` with the variables in your code containing these values.

Comment: Please find [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579730/ms-access-send-email-not-from-outlook-or-users-email?rq=1) code for sending email via gmail (or other internet mail services, as Yahoo).